# How to stretch width of the a single button in v-tour to 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

The maximum width of this popup I can achieve here is 250px.

[image]

Now, I want to stretch the button to the entire popup's width.

Below is the piece of code I tried-

```
<div slot="actions" style="width: 250px; text-align: left;">
  <button @click="signup()" class="btn btn-primary btn-next" style="width: 250px;">Sign up</button>
</div>
```

My expectations-

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using width: 100%; instead of width: 250px; for dive and button?

Comment: Please post a fiddle with the existing problem so that someone can check the real issue.

Comment: did you check in dev tools the real "computed" width of the button? There is certainly a property given by css class or user agent which block your button size

Comment: thanks it worked using min-width instead of width! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap try with  "btn-block" class

Comment: Can you add a working example and the full line of html inside brackets ?